# Java reading text project

Tags: java

Hi guys I make a project in java to read text file but it doesn't work i hope you can help me

```
package read_file;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Demo {


public static void main(String[] args) {
BufferedReader br= null;



try{
br= new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hp\\workspace\\MyFFFFProject"));


String line ; 

while ((line=br.readLine())!= null ) { 
    System.out.println(line);
}
}catch (IOException e){ 
e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
try{
    br.close();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

}
```

in the console this message appear for me

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\hp\workspace\MyFFFFProject (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at read_file.Demo.main(Demo.java:11)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at read_file.Demo.main(Demo.java:21)
```

the file i want to read is NotePad++ contain are :-

```
this is my file content line 1
this is my file content line 2
this is my file content line 3
this is my file content line 4
this is my file content line 5
this is my file content line 6
this is my file content line 7
```

Comment: The exception says "(Access is denied)"... Is the file opened in other apps, like Notepad++?

Comment: You could use `Files.readLines` and pass a `Path` object.

Comment: Are you sure `MyFFFFProject` is a file and not a folder?

Comment: Could you [fix your indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44589299/edit) please? There is no reason code should look like this.

Comment: Welcome in `java.io.File` where every exception are `FileNotFound`, the message is more important than the type of exception here.

Comment: i think that this line: `br= new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hp\\workspace\\MyFFFFProject"));` ¿ you forget tu put the extension maybe? i recomend you to use a Resource Try to manage files in java it will close automatically , you wont need to do the .close() method

Answer (score 0):

check your file permissions.Seems you(or the user who is running the program)  does not have read permissions for this particular file. 
I have a linux box and tried the same code, it worked. I forced to put no read permission for me and got the same error.

Comment: Have you checked it?